# How to use hook_form_alter in the .theme file to alter the form fields?

Tags: forms, hooks

I need to know how to use hook_form_alter in .theme file as i have to alter the form fields related to user_register_form.

I tried putting the below code in the .theme file but it does not even reach the function

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function hook_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  // Adding custom validation for the welcome page type field.
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
     print_r('Reaching in here');exit;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to alter a specific form, and you know the ID, use [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.5.x) rather than the generic version:

```
function THEMENAME_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Add alterations specific to the user registration form
}
```

Make sure you clear the cache after renaming the function.

Comment: This worked well Great Thanks. Though i had to use the interface : use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;